# Check if the number is registered in Viber, WhatsApp or iMessage

Tags: database, whatsapp, messenger, imessage, viber

I have a database of 4500 phone numbers. I would like to check if these numbers are registered in one of the messengers. Is there a ready-made solution for doing that?

Comment: Did you find your answer?? I have a similar issue like this with iMessage. @Vlad117

Answer (score 1):

You can try start chat with viber user using deep link. If the chat is open, this user exists.

Comment: Any ideas how to that without own viber account?